# How to pause/sleep child processer

Tags: c, sleep

I have program to make children process to delay for certain amount of time.
But if I use sleep() function, somehow it freezes another processes as well.
I have used timer implementation using clock() function but it has very heavy computational and CPU wastes resulting delaying other processes as well.
How do i deal with it?

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question, otherwise it will be hard to tell what you are doing wrong.

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Show us your code please.